# Not able to capture canceled requests using browsermobproxy

Tags: browsermob, browsermob-proxy

In my website I am getting canceled requests in network traffic. But I am not able to capture them in browsermobproxy har file. How can I get canceled request in har file.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Response not recorded for interrupted requests is a known issue.

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Browsermob
- Browsermob-proxy

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** Developer wishes to track requets in HAR file but, some requests are either malformed completely missing.

#### Solution

- This is a known issue, this has been raised in the issue queue and patched

#### See also

- https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/285

Comment: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/285 this issue closed saying fixed. But I am still facing this issue. and I am using dependency,    
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
   <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4</version>
  </dependency>